Why is a Double Stochastic Matrix important?
I am confused about the concept of a Double Stochastic Matrix.
Here is my understanding.

Double Stochastic Matrix: A square matrix of nonnegative numbers, where each of its rows and columns sums to 1.
$$
A = [a_{ij}] \quad \text{such that} \quad a_{ij} \geq 0, \quad \sum_{i} a_{ij} = 1, \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{j} a_{ij} = 1 \quad \forall i,j
$$

Here is an example:
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3 \\
0.4 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
0.4 & 0.4 & 0.2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Non-Double Stochastic Matrix: A square matrix of nonnegative numbers, where each of its rows and columns do not need to sum to 1.

$$
A = [a_{ij}] \quad \text{such that} \quad a_{ij} \geq 0, \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{i} a_{ij} = 1 \quad \forall j
$$
Here is an example (note: a transition matrix for a markov chain does not necessarily have to be doubly stochastic):
$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3 \\
0.4 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4\end{pmatrix}$$
Based on this - my question:
Why is this distinction of Double Stochastic even noteworthy? For example, do Double Stochastic matrices have some special properties that make them more applicable/useful in certain situations?

they are featured rather prominently in the theory of majorization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization including Birkhoff - von Neumann

They show up a lot in allocation problems like the house allocation problem or fair random assignment problems. They also appear in network flow problems in graph theory. Birkhoff's algorithm lets them be decomposed into convex combinations of permutation matrices which can be useful computationally.

Application to markov chains: The stationary distribution of an irreducible aperiodic finite Markov chain is uniform if and only if its transition matrix is doubly stochastic.
